# Create taxonomy 'add terms' form into block

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

I have two vocabularies named 'vocab_one' and 'vocab_two'. I create custom multiple blocks module named 'add library', in order to display the taxonomy 'add terms' form to each blocks.

Each block displayed on the same node in the content area. The position of 'Vocab Two Block' are above 'Vocab One Block'.

When I add new term on 'Vocab One Block', the new term is always stored in the 'vocab_two'. Then I switch position of the block. This time, the new term is always stored in the 'vocab_one'.

How to store a new term within selected vocabulary, without worrying about the block position?

here is my add_library.module:

```
function add_library_block_info() {
  $blocks['Vocab Two Block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Vocab Two'),
  );

  $blocks['Vocab Two Block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Vocab One'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function add_library_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'Vocab Two Block':
      $block['subject'] = t('Add Vocab Two');
      $block['content'] = add_vocab_two();
      break;
    case 'Vocab Two Block':
      $block['subject'] = t('Add Vocab One');
      $block['content'] = add_vocab_one();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function add_vocab_two() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
    $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load(2);
    return drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary);
}

function add_vocab_one() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
    $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load(4);
    return drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary);
}
```